# SQL Server Query / View Single Line Output For Combined Multiple Data Elements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following 2 tables in SQL Server:

Table #1 - `TENDERED`

```
DATE  
DOC_NO
PMNT_SEQ_NO
PAYCODE_TYPE
AMOUNT

--> Primary Key = DATE / DOC_NO / PAYMENT_SEQ_NO
```

Table #2. `TENDERED_CR_CARD`

```
DATE
DOC_NO
PMNT_SEQ_NO
CR_CARD_NO_MASKED
CR_CARD_NAME
CR_CARD_EXP_DATE

-->Primary Key = DATE / DOC_NO / PAYMENT_SEQ_NO
```

These two tables are certainly related, based on their Primary Key values.

Now, consider the following data in those two tables:

```
DATE        DOC_NO  PMNT_SEQ_NO PAYCODE_TYPE    AMOUNT
03/10/2014  100001     1            CASH            100.00
03/10/2014  100001     2            CASH             -9.75
03/10/2014  100002     1            CASH             50.00
03/10/2014  100002     2            VISA            100.00
03/10/2014  100002     3            VISA            250.00
03/10/2014  100003     1            MC              125.00
03/10/2014  100003     2            AMEX            75.00

DATE        DOC_NO PMNT_SEQ_NO  CR_CARD_MASKED    NAME  CR_CARD_EXP
03/10/2014  100002   2            4225******801289  MARY JONES  2016/08/31
03/10/2014  100002   3            4121******637442  JOHN DOE    2015/04/30
03/10/2014  100003   1            5428******971134  MIKE BAKER  2018/09/30
03/10/2014  100003   2            3732*****344756   LINDA LIU   2017/07/31
```

OK...so what we NEED...is a Combined, SINGLE RECORD Audit Report type query.  The resulting query should show, based on the Data from above, the SINGLE LINE represented in the Spreadsheet-type Format below.  NOTE...what's important to point out here..is that ONLY the 'CASH' Tender gets "summed"...EACH INDIVIDUAL Credit Card record MUST have its own Field...as represented in the corresponding Columns of the Spreadsheet (i.e. PMT_TYP_1, AMT_1, PMT_TYP_2, AMT_2, and so forth).

PLEASE HELP!  Any suggestions/advice would be most appreciated!  Thank You!...Mark

OUTPUT FORMAT:

```
DATE    DOC_NO  PMNT_TYP_1  AMT_1   CR_CARD_MASK_1  NAME_1  CR_CARD_EXP_1   PMNT_TYP_2  AMT_2   CR_CARD_MASK_2  NAME_2  CR_CARD_EXP_2   PMNT_TYP_3  AMT_3   CR_CARD_MASK_3  NAME_3  CR_CARD_EXP_3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this question, or at least a good starting point.

Note below I have a set of code marked as CODE BLOCK 1 -- this could be made into a stored procedure, and if you un-comment the ALTER VIEW line in the dynamic SQL at the bottom, the proc could re-build a view.  We do this currently for a reporting platform that is unable to call a proc or run this code.  So we have a trigger fire the proc when new rows are added to a particular table, and alter the view automatically.  The reporting platform just has to do a SELECT at that point.  Note, since the proc alters, you have to manually create a view of the same name (could be any schema), then the proc will fix it.

Good luck!!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TENDERED') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TENDERED
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TENDERED_CD_CARD') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TENDERED_CD_CARD

CREATE TABLE #TENDERED (DATE DATETIME, DOC_NO INT, PMNT_SEQ_NO INT, PAYCODE_TYPE NVARCHAR(10), AMOUNT MONEY)
CREATE TABLE #TENDERED_CD_CARD (DATE DATETIME, DOC_NO INT, PMNT_SEQ_NO INT, CR_CARD_NO_MASKED NVARCHAR(16), CR_CARD_NAME NVARCHAR(255), CR_CARD_EXP_DATE NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TENDERED
SELECT '03/10/2014',100001,1,'CASH',100.00 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100001,2,'CASH',-9.75 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100002,1,'CASH',50.00 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100002,2,'VISA',100.00 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100002,3,'VISA',250.00 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100003,1,'MC',125.00 UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100003,2,'AMEX',75.00

INSERT INTO #TENDERED_CD_CARD
SELECT '03/10/2014',100002,2,'4225******801289','MARY JONES','2016/08/31' UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100002,3,'4121******637442','JOHN DOE','2015/04/30' UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100003,1,'5428******971134','MIKE BAKER','2018/09/30' UNION ALL
SELECT '03/10/2014',100003,2,'3732*****344756','LINDA LIU','2017/07/31'

/* BEGIN CODE BLOCK 1 */
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @y    AS INT, 
        @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @COLNAME TABLE (COLNAME NVARCHAR(75), OB INT, PMNT_SEQ_NO INT)

INSERT INTO @COLNAME (COLNAME, OB, PMNT_SEQ_NO)
SELECT DISTINCT 'PAYCODE_TYPE_'+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, 1 AS OB, T.PMNT_SEQ_NO 
FROM #TENDERED T
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'AMT_'+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, 2, T.PMNT_SEQ_NO 
FROM #TENDERED T
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'CR_CARD_MASK_'+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, 3, T.PMNT_SEQ_NO  
FROM #TENDERED T
JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'NAME_'+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, 4, T.PMNT_SEQ_NO 
FROM #TENDERED T
JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'CR_CARD_EXP_'+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, 5, T.PMNT_SEQ_NO 
FROM #TENDERED T
JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO

SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLNAME AS y, PMNT_SEQ_NO, OB FROM (SELECT COLNAME, PMNT_SEQ_NO, OB FROM @COLNAME ) AS sub
      ) AS Y
ORDER BY PMNT_SEQ_NO, OB
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

print @cols

SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.DATE, 101) AS DATE, T.DOC_NO, ''PAYCODE_TYPE_''+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, PAYCODE_TYPE AS VAL
                     FROM #TENDERED T
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.DATE, 101) AS DATE, T.DOC_NO, ''AMT_''+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, CAST(AMOUNT AS NVARCHAR) AS VAL
                     FROM #TENDERED T
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.DATE, 101) AS DATE, T.DOC_NO, ''CR_CARD_MASK_''+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, CR_CARD_NO_MASKED AS VAL
                     FROM #TENDERED T
                     JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.DATE, 101) AS DATE, T.DOC_NO, ''NAME_''+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, CR_CARD_NAME AS VAL
                     FROM #TENDERED T
                     JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.DATE, 101) AS DATE, T.DOC_NO, ''CR_CARD_EXP_''+CAST(T.PMNT_SEQ_NO AS NVARCHAR) AS COLNAME, CR_CARD_EXP_DATE AS VAL
                     FROM #TENDERED T
                     JOIN #TENDERED_CD_CARD T2 ON T.DATE=T2.DATE AND T.DOC_NO=T2.DOC_NO AND T.PMNT_SEQ_NO=T2.PMNT_SEQ_NO
                     ) AS sub) AS D
PIVOT(max(VAL) FOR COLNAME IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P
ORDER BY DATE, DOC_NO;';

--set @sql = N'ALTER VIEW vwMyPaymentSummary as ' + @sql
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
/* END CODE BLOCK 1 */
```

Comment: Hi Jiggs...thank you SOOOOO much for chiming in here...it's very much appreciated!  Question...in your example above, the only thing I don't see (and maybe I'm missing it)...is the "summation" of all of the 'CASH' type PayCode lines.  Thoughts?  Thanks!...Mark

Comment: Based on the requirements of the credit cards in their own fields, there's no clean way to crowbar a SUM into this.  Pivot can do a SUM operation, but not when you have non-numerics in the fields.  You could copy the above, and use one for cash only, and one for credit cards, but if a customer pays both ways, you'd have two lines for that customer.  Even if we could SUM, what if they pay by credit card first, then cash, do you sum in type 1 or type 2?  Maybe someone else has a better solution, but I'd handle this cash exception (and it is an exception to me) in the front end logic.